# Instrumentação de JVM. Saber quantas vezes um método foi chamado durante a execução do programa

Tags: java, jvm

Tenho uma aplicação de processamento de `batch`, atualmente ela é `multithreads`, preciso saber quantas vezes estamos executando o método salvar.

Alguém teria alguma ideia? Pois preciso aumentar o número de `threads` durante a noite e gostaria de ter algum parâmetro para esta minha decisão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com o que você falou, você tem um método salvar, deve ser estático ou não. Seja como for, você quer saber quantas vezes ele é executado. durante um período de tempo.

**Use AspecjJ**

Com AspectJ, você será capaz de lastrear o numero de execuções de determinados métodos.

Sugiro que você decida entre salvar essa informação para um arquivo de log, ou incrementar uma variável que você possa ler posteriormente.

**Como?**

Vou partir do pressuposto de que você está utilizando Maven para gerenciar o ciclo de vida dos seus builds. Primeiramente, tenha as dependencias do AspectJ, você vai precisar dos seguintes artefatos:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Agora, crie um JoinPoint Para os métodos desejados:

```
//A seguinte classe deve servir de template para você:
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class TrackingMethodsAspect {

    public long volatile executedTimes = 0;

    @Before("execution(* SuaClasse.seuMetodo(..))")
    public void track(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        executedTimes++;
    }

}
```

Nesta estratégia, posteriormente você pode ler o valor escrito para variável executedTimes e tomar decisões de como melhor gerenciar suas threads, e a quantidade de objetos.

O que o AspectJ fará serpa instrumentar suas classes, no caso seu método e permitir que você insira byde-codes. Tanto em *runtime* quanto em *buildtime*

E por último e não menos importante utilize o plugin do AspectJ para que efetivamente a instrumentação aconteça.

Você deve ter este plugin na sessão de plugins do POM.XML

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal><!-- to weave all your main classes -->
        <goal>test-compile</goal><!-- to weave all your test classes -->
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
  <configuration>
  <weaveDependencies>
  <weaveDependency>
  <groupId>com.seuprojeto</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjectB</artifactId>
  </weaveDependency>
  </weaveDependencies>
  <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>    
  <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
  <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

No exemple acima a instrumentação ocorrerá em ***build-time***
E não em ***runtime***, é importante se atentar a esse detalhe.

Comment: É um bom caminho sim, achei até interessante a abordagem. Na realidade utilizo o gradle para o build das aplicações.

Comment: @Flávio Granato Você aplicar aspectos em Runtime. E também é possível sim utilizar aspectJ sem O Maven. E também tem a flexibilidade de usar com Spring(AspectJ + Spring.)
Cheque esse tutorial, você conseguir instrumentar bem rápido com essas técnicas:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/